# I have error on the JQuery DataTable. JQuery Datatable works fine on the local enviornment while on hosted enviornment, it gives error

Tags: javascript, jquery, server, hosting, client-side-scripting

[image]I am using the JQuery Datatable in the MVC5 application along with WebApi. But when I'm running my application on my local environment, it works fine and when I host it on the server it gives me error.
For more information I am attaching screenshot. Please provide the resolution for it.

We tried with try catch also tried to find the specific error but not reproducing.

JQuery datatable should display the proper data without error.

Comment: Please share your datatable initialization code

Comment: calling the data through the ajax call and web api.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no issue in JQuery tables but with your service call. it returns invalid JSON response.

refer to this link.
https://datatables.net/manual/tech-notes/1

Comment: how could I verify my JSON response? any suggestion!

Comment: I assume you are calling web api, kindly check the service in production environment. it should return the valid JSON response.

Comment: did you handle exceptions? and log them? might be they can help!

Comment: if you have the production access, try to debug.

Comment: get the web.config file from production and check with your local code

Comment: There might be issue with Json Length in production. are you using c#?

Comment: JsonResult result = Json(your_data, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
result.MaxJsonLength = Int32.MaxValue;
return result;

Answer (score 0):

It is because of the invalid `ajax` request respons. Data table expects `json` where your `api` failed to give it. Check the `network` tab of `inspect element` and verify the response.
[Check for details: Ajax data binding](https://datatables.net/examples/ajax/objects.html)

Comment: How could I verify my JSON response? any suggestion!

Answer (score 0):

Issue occurred due to null value getting from the database.
hence for this kind of problem, check the value getting from the Database.